# How to generate SSH private key using AWS secret manager rotation for custom lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I've integrated AWS secret manager (ASM) for rotating SSH private keys. All thing works fine. I'm able to SSH on my Linux instance using the retrieved secret key value by the [get-secret-value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets.html) command.

Also, I've created a custom lambda function in ruby, for rotating my secret(SSK key) as below.

```
require 'json'
require 'aws-sdk-secretsmanager'
require 'base64'

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)

    event['SecretId'] = "my-secret-id"
    region = 'my-region'

    arn = event['SecretId']
    token = event['ClientRequestToken']
    step = event['Step']    
    
    client = Aws::SecretsManager::Client.new(region: region)
     
    
    metadata = client.describe_secret(secret_id: arn)
   
        versions = metadata[:version_ids_to_stages]        
    
        if metadata[:rotation_enabled] == false
            puts "Secret %s is not enabled for rotation" % arn
        end
        
    if step == "createSecret"
        create_secret(client, arn, token)

    elsif step == "setSecret"
        set_secret(client, arn, token)

    elsif step == "testSecret"
        test_secret(client, arn, token)

    elsif step == "finishSecret"
        finish_secret(client, arn, token)

    else
        puts "Invalid step parameter"
         create_secret(client, arn, token)
        return
    end     
    
        { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.generate('Hello from Lambda!') }
end


def create_secret(client, arn, token)
    
    client.get_secret_value(secret_id: arn, version_stage: "AWSCURRENT")
    
    begin
        client.get_secret_value(secret_id: arn, version_id: token, version_stage: "AWSPENDING")
        puts "createSecret: Successfully retrieved secret for %s." % arn
    rescue
        puts "Not found secret with label AWSPENDING"

        # Here I want to generate a new SSH key and encode it,
        # For Database passwords rotation `client.get_random_password(password_length: "desired length", exclude_characters: "ExcludeCharactersType")` option is available, but for SSH I'm unable to find the generate method
        
    end
end
```

If anyone has an idea about how to generate a `new ssh private key` inside the `create_secret` method then please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function is implementation is incomplete and missing some of the steps described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotate-secrets_how.html). You need to use the [generic template](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRotationTemplate/lambda_function.py), written in python and adapt it for Ruby.

In create_secret you generate the key:

- If you need an EC2 key pair, see this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/ec2-create-key-pair.html).
- If you need a generate public/private key pair, sample code is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-create-public-private-key.html).

In set_secret you need to update the ssh key in your Linux instances. Before changing your ssh configuration, you need to test that the new key works.

In the optional test_secret step, you test, if you can use the secret to connect.

In finish_secret you label the new secret as the current one.

Comment: thank you for your guidance. But I edited my question, actually, I want to know the way I can generate SSH key inside `create_secret` method. please guide me about it if possible.

Comment: See updated answer. It depends on what exactly you need. Also, you will need to set the key in your Linux instance. Provide more details to get help on this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using the above link I'm able to generate my EC2 private key.
I have confusion regarding setting private key and public key on Linux instance. do we need to modify it manually or AWS secret manager takes care of it? Also, how do EC2 recognize that the generated key is for that instance only, while we created according to [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/ec2-create-key-pair.html) you provided above.

Comment: Kindly note that I have deployed my code using a separate user other than ec2-user, which means one extra sure is there for deployment and I'm configuring a secret key for that only.